# setting up nginx and two sails app on a server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, config, nginx-location

I have two different application one acts as a backend panel whereas one app is client facing site.

I have set the client site on the default 80 port and backend panel app is on say port number 8000.

I am facing issue when i try to bind wwww.abc.com:8000 to www.abc.com/admin. On opening of the link, text do gets displayed but css and js is not getting loaded. I found in console that its says CSS and javascript files are not found.  Also, the address it specifies for css and javascript is of the root folder and not of the backend panel folder.

Here is the code I have written to setup nginx to bind the route is here

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abc.com

    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }

    location ^~ /admin {
        root              /root/workspace/lexcarts-admin-panel;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect    on;
    }
}
```

Client app is accessible from default www.abc.com .

Please guide me where i am going wrong.

TIA

Comment: You have to add in the config where to look for your static files. (CSS, JS)

Comment: @Jclarke i have added root information under location "root      /root/workspace/lexcarts-admin-panel; " to refer for root folder and then fetch the files which is defined using relative paths in the app. Is there anything else i need to add?

Comment: for server name you need to put the wild card character `*` or add the names explicitly `server_name abc.com www.abc.com ;` or `*abc.com;` and close your server name statement.

Comment: Can you post the full URI that it's trying to access? eg `http://localhost/static/css/style.css`